# How to create an EOS account using eosjs without existing account and its private key

Tags: eosjs

I have a question about EOS, eosio and eosjs.

I want to create an EOS account using frontend website that I developed. I I recognize that creating an account needs existing account, and needs its private key. But, I think putting a private key on frontend website is so danger.

Let me know how to create account without existing account and its private key.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Account creation in EOSIO is done by `newaccount` action, so there should be a pre-existing account to send that. Moreover, new account needs RAM allocation, so its cost also needs to be paid by the account which creates other one.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
I tried newaccount on testnet. I got known only "eosio" account can create new account on testnet.
Should I create account by "eosio" account on testnet and mainnet?
And, tell me how to create new account using "eosio" account.

Comment: No, any account can creates new account by sending action to `eosio` account. Action sender is different from action receiver. What testnet did you use? In jungle, or kyrin, you can create account via web frontend, and after that, you can create another new account from newly created account.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar concerns.
I tried to create an EOS account when signing up on the web.
So, I used a method of providing a private key to the user upon completion of membership registration ( alert )...

How did you solve it?